# Join two tables and ignore data in duplicate columns

Tags: php

I have two tables `machine_info` and `parts_repalced`

table `machine_info`

```
id | machine_name | desc | date_added | parts_ref
1  | printer      | desc1| 09/09/15   | 7
```

table `parts_replaced`

```
id | machine_ref_id | partno | qty
1  | 7              | KFRy23 | 2
2  | 7              | RY7RA1 | 4
```

Now I want it to join and display like this

```
id | machine_name | desc | date_added | partno | qty
1  | printer      | desc1| 09/09/15   | KFRy23 | 2
                                      | RY7RA1 | 4
```

here is what i have done so far..

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM machine_info LEFT OUTER JOIN parts_replaced ON machine_info.id = parts_replaced.machine_ref_id");

$data = "";
while($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if ($data != "") {$data .= ",";}
    $data .= '{"id":"'  . $r->id . '",';
    $data .= '"machine_name":"'   . $r->machine_name. '",';
    $data .= '"desc":"'   . $r->desc. '",';
    $data .= '"date_added":"'   . $r->date_added. '",';
    $data .= '"partno":"'   . $r->partno. '",';
    $data .= '"qty":"'. $r->qty. '"}'; 
    }
    $result->free();
$data ='{"records":['.$data.']}';
$db->close();
echo($data);
```

the problem with the result is it give me a duplicate result

Comment: Hi. You put `php` tag, but i don't see any php problem. Maybe you'd like to add additional info?

Comment: Just add a DISTINCT clause, like this `SELECT DISTINCT   machine_info.id,  machine_info.desc, parts_replaced.partno FROM machine_info LEFT OUTER JOIN ...etc`

Comment: hi @SergeyChizhik i updated the info..

Comment: I don't have an answer on first glance mostly because I don't really understand what you mean by "give me a duplicate result" - can you post what the table you are getting looks like?  I like the way you've formatted the table and what you want to get, I'd like to also see what you are getting to understand the problem better.

Comment: `id | machine_name | desc   | date_added | partno    | qty`
`1  | printer               | desc1 | 09/09/15      | KFRy23  | 2`
`1  | printer               | desc1 | 09/09/15      | RY7RA1  | 4`

this is what i got @CBRF23

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand. Put all your results in an array, and use `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY machine_ref_id` in the query, so all the rows for the same machine will be together. Then change your display code so it puts blanks in the first 4 columns if `machine_ref_id` is the same as the previous row.

You could also do that in the code that creates the JSON, by putting blanks in those fields:

```
$last_id = null;
$results = array();
while ($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if ($r->id === $last_id) {
        $results[] = array(
            'id' => '',
            'machine_name' => '',
            'desc' => '',
            'date_added' => '',
            'partno' => $r->partno,
            'qty' => $r->qty
        );
    } else {
        $results[] = array(
            'id' => $r->id,
            'machine_name' => $r->machine_name,
            'desc' => $r->desc,
            'date_added' => $r->date_added,
            'partno' => $r->partno,
            'qty' => $r->qty
        );
        $last_id = $r->id;
    }
}
$db->close();
echo json_encode(array('records' => $results));
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are missing one or more key fields in your join.  If not, you should consider adding a GROUP BY clause or selecting DISTINCT.

Comment: `DISTINCT` won't help because the `partno` and `qty` are different on each row. And `GROUP BY` will omit the row for the second `partno`.